# Detecting screen transition (switching) globally in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I was wondering if there is a way to detect screen switching globally in the app, e.g. from Application Delegate? I know there are methods like isMovingFromParentViewController() and isMovingToParentViewController(), but those can only be used locally. Any info would be helpful, thanks!

Kristian

Comment: You can override `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` and post notification from there.

Comment: Hi, it can be detected globally from `AppDelegate` if you use an `UINavigationController` as a `ContainerView` for all the `UIViewController`s in your app. You can check my answer for more info

Comment: Hi, have you already found solution this question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use a global `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` for the `UIWindow` in the `AppDelegate` in the following way.

```
let navigationController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
navigationController.delegate = self

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Then the following delegate methods in `UINavigationControllerDelegate` will do the work in `AppDelegate`

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

}
```

The above functions will help you when a new `UIViewController` shows up in `UINavigationController`. Unfortunately, there are no such methods related to `UIWindow` to observe those changes. Please let me know if it helps.